# Why is a form's onsubmit function only called once?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

Pretty much what it says on the tin.  This snippet demonstrates the problem:

```js
function check(e) {
  console.log($('input[name="myinput"]').val());
  if ($('input[name="myinput"]').val() == "123") {
    return true;
  } else {
    $('input[name="myinput"]')[0].setCustomValidity("Invalid");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form onsubmit="return check()">
    <input name="myinput">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

When the form loads, enter `1` into the input field and submit the form.  Submission fails because the input field's value was not `123`, and the value `"1"` is logged in the console.  Now change the value to anything else and resubmit the form; there is no extra line in the console and the "Invalid" form validity remains even if the value entered is `123`.

Why is the `onsubmit` handler only called once?

Comment: @NenadVracar So what can I do?  Register an `onchange` handler that resets the custom validity every time a field changes?

Comment: Yeah, That's one way to go @Tom.

Comment: Soooo, how is my answer going? We waste free time here for you. At least give a bit of feedback... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a form in an "invalid" state (because an input inside the form is in "invalid" state) won't submit.

Form validity is created not to be changed on `submit` events because, as you noticed, you won't get any new `submit`. You must change the form validity before submitting it. Usually, form validity is checked individually on each input. From here is on your own taste. I would recommend checking the validity of each input on `blur`:

```
$('input[name="myinput"]').on("blur", () => {
    // Do your checks and setCustomValidity depending on if is valid or not
});
```

This way, you only will receive a `submit` event if all inputs are valid. By the way, for this to work, you must set all inputs to an invalid state on startup, to avoid empty submits without touching any input.

Another way could be to disable the submit button if all inputs are empty. For this, you will also need JavaScript and check the `change` or `input` events on all inputs.